# Django with lettuce and splinter, opens the browser but doesn't show anything

Tags: python, django, lettuce

I am trying my hands on lettuce with splinter. I have a django app which is well configured, no issues with that. When i try running lettuce, with the step which "should" visit a url in the browser, it doesn't returns any error but it doesn't shows up the page.

Here is my .feature file :

```
Feature: A test 
Scenario: User enters email, ajax will check if it exists
    When I go to the "/home/login/" URL 
    Then I fill in "#id_email" with "abc@def.gih"
```

here is my steps.py

```
from lettuce import *
from lettuce.django import django_url
from lxml import html
from django.test.client import Client
from nose.tools import assert_equals
from splinter.browser import Browser
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment, teardown_test_environment
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import connection
from django.conf import settings

@before.all
def set_browser():
    setup_test_environment()
    world.browser = Browser('firefox')

@step(u'I go to the "(.*)" URL')
def i_go_to_the_url(step, url):
    world.response = world.browser.visit(django_url(url))

@step(u'I fill in "(.*)" with "(.*)"')
def i_fill_in(step, field, value):
    world.browser.fill(field, value)
```

It opens the browser, the browser doesn't shows up anything but the test succeeds, and the second case fails with the following error :

```
Feature: A test        # candidate/feature/index.feature:1

  Scenario: User enters email, ajax will check if it exists # candidate/feature/index.feature:3
    When I go to the "/home/login/" URL             # home/feature/index-steps.py:29
    Then I fill in "email" with "dsfdf@safsdfsd"       # home/feature/index-steps.py:39
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lettuce/core.py", line 117, in __call__
        ret = self.function(self.step, *args, **kw)
      File "********/candidate/feature/index-steps.py", line 40, in i_fill_in
        world.browser.fill(field, value)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 240, in fill
        field.value = value
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 306, in _set_value
        self._element.clear()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear'

1 feature (0 passed)
1 scenario (0 passed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 passed)
(finished within 15 seconds)
```

Please can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't explain a lot, but maybe try the following

```
    world.browser.find_by_id(field).fill(value)
```

Comment: In case it helps others, you are passing in an ID so you need to find_by_id. If you want to use your original fill method you need to pass in the field name.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem. Write:

```
When I go to the "http://0.0.0.0:8000/home/login/" URL
```

insted of

```
When I go to the "/home/login/" URL
```

and everything will be fine!

Comment: django_url(...) is doing that - you shouldn't hard-code the full url in case the test server starts on a different port